# Assigning IDs to React components to add to state and map over in the render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am building a form in React. I have an add button to duplicate a form block and a remove button to remove that form block.

I've added `blockIds` when the component gets rendered and this is the problem:

When there are multiple instances of the form blocks on the page, eg.

Doctor 1
Doctor 2
Doctor 3
Doctor 4

and I want to remove Doctor 2, `removeFormBlock` removes the block with the `blockId=doctor_1` (zero-indexed), but when `doctorFormBlocks` re-renders on the form, new `blockIds` are being generated and assigned and do not match what is in `this.state.doctoFormBlocks`.

How should I be approaching this, ie. where should I be generating the `blockId`s? I tried in `<DoctorFormBlock>` but the trouble is passing the id back up to `appendFormBlock` and `removeFormBlock` in `<DoctorsForm>`.

I also initialised the first block (never removed) in `this.state. doctorFormBlocks`. Not sure if this is right either.

```
class DoctorsForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

            ...

            this.state = {
                title,
                form,
                content,
                doctorFormBlocks: ['doctor_0'],
            };

            ...
    }

    appendFormBlock(e) {
        const newBlock = `doctor_${this.state.doctorFormBlocks.length}`;

        this.setState({
            doctorFormBlocks: this.state.doctorFormBlocks.concat([newBlock]),
        });
    }

    removeFormBlock(e) {
        const blockToRemoveId = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;

        this.setState(
            {doctorFormBlocks: this.state.doctorFormBlocks.filter(block => block !== blockToRemoveId)},
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (

            ...

            <div className="form__section">
                <h2>{content.treatingDoctorsTitle}</h2>
                <RichText content={HtmlEntity.decode(content.treatingDoctorsText)} />

                {doctorFormBlocks.map((block, i) => (
                    <DoctorFormBlock
                        form={form}
                        key={i}
                        blockId={`doctor-${i}`}
                        id={i + 1}
                        handleRemove={this.removeFormBlock.bind(this)}
                    />
                ))}

                <AddRemoveButton typeToAdd="doctor" handleAppend={this.appendFormBlock.bind(this)} />
            </div>

            ...

        )
    }
}

class DoctorFormBlock extends React.Component {

    ...

    render() {
        const {form, id, blockId, handleRemove} = this.props;

        return (
            <section className="form__block" id={blockId}>
                {id > 1 && <AddRemoveButton isRemove handleRemove={handleRemove} />}

                <h3>Doctor {id}</h3>

                <LayoutField form={form} fieldId="doctorsSpeciality" sectionId="doctorDetailsForm" />
                <LayoutField form={form} fieldId="name" sectionId="doctorDetailsForm" />
                <LayoutField form={form} fieldId="address" sectionId="doctorDetailsForm" />
                <LayoutField form={form} fieldId="contactNumber" sectionId="doctorDetailsForm" />
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `appendFormBlock` to set all the block Ids?

Comment: @Tyler I'm calling `appendFormBlock` in `onClick={handleAppend}`  of `<AddRemoveButton>`. It's working fine, just buggy when removing form blocks due to the ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is on this line of code:

```
blockId={`doctor-${i}`}
```

This is more or less "doctor-" + currentIndex

Since you are looping through an array, your ids will be in line (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc). So when you remove 1, and it re-renders. It would be like (0, 1, 2, 3). Notice the missing 4.

I believe you should be using `block` like following:

```
blockId={block}
```

Besides your original problem, there is some very probable headaches we should clear up now and other code-smells.

---

#### e.target vs e.currentTarget

Be careful with `e.target`. `e.target` has a tendency to change what element it is referring to. You probably want `e.currentTarget`.

`currentTarget` always refers to the element that the event is attached to. See the [documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) for more information.

---

#### element.parentNode.parentNode.nightmare

Regarding `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;`. That `parentNode.parentNode` is a nightmare. If you want to go up 1 `parentNode` okay... Once you start going up multiple, you are losing track of where you are going.

This can be avoided by just passing in the id as a parameter to `removeFormBlock`.

```
removeFormBlock(id) {
    this.setState(
        {doctorFormBlocks: this.state.doctorFormBlocks.filter(block => block !== id)},
    );
}

//And in your JSX element
<AddRemoveButton isRemove handleRemove={() => { handleRemove(blockId) } } />
```

What we are doing here, is making the AddRemoveButton's handleRemove refer to an anonymous function. That anonymous function will then call `handleRemove` and pass in `blockId`.
That way we can access the blockId through function parameter instead of a nightmare of parentNodes.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips :) `blockId={block}` solved the issue. It seemed that `push` didn't work because I couldn't push to an array in `setState`. `concat`   made more sense in this context.

Comment: @dho Hmmm... It seems I might have misunderstood one of the difference between push and concat. Yea, I had thought array.push creates a new array and returns it; however, the documentation is saying it returns the new length of the array. My bad, concat is actually more appriopriate in your situation.